# Checking response Time of API in iOS using Swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, performance, response

I know to test the response time of API is basically done by Server or Backend side, but as i am working for one application, i need to check api response time from iOS End also.

How can i do this ? i read few links where it says to do this using timer start and timer end and then find the response time by **endTime - startTime**  but this seems not handy.

I want to use Xcode (even if XCTest is there).

Here is my one of API ( i wrote all web service consume method in separate class in ApiManager class  ) :

**LoginVC** :

```
//Call Webservice
let apiManager      = ApiManager()
apiManager.delegate = self
apiManager.getUserInfoAPI()
```

**ApiManager** :

```
func getUserInfoAPI()  {
    //Header
    let headers =       [
        "Accept"        : "application/json",
        "Content-Type"  : "application/json",
    ]

    //Call Web API using Alamofire library
    AlamoFireSharedManagerInit()
    Alamofire.request(HCConstants.URL, method: .post, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON {  response in

        do{
            //Checking For Error
            if let error = response.result.error {
                //Stop AcitivityIndicator
                self.hideHud()
                //Call failure delegate method
                //print(error)
                  self.delegate?.APIFailureResponse(HCConstants.EXCEPTION_MESSAGES.SERVICE_FAILURE)
                return
            }

            //Store Response
            let responseValue = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: response.data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions()) as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
            print(responseValue)

            //Save token 
            if let mEmail = responseValue[HCConstants.Email] as? String {
                UserDefaults.standard.setValue(mEmail, forKey: HCConstants. mEmail)
            }

            //Stop AcitivityIndicator
            self.hideHud()
            //Check Success Flag
            if let _ = responseValue["info"] as? String {
                //Call success delegate method
                self.delegate?.apiSuccessResponse(responseValue)
            }
            else {
                //Failure message
                self.delegate?.APIFailureResponse(responseValue["message"] as? String ?? HCConstants.EXCEPTION_MESSAGES.SERVICE_FAILURE)
            }

        } catch {print("Exception is there "}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Using Alamofire, you can use `response.timeline.totalDuration`, otherwise see the solution below that doesn't require any 3rd party libraries.

There's no need for a `Timer`, you can just use `Date` objects. You should create a `Date` object representing the current date at the time of starting your API request and in the completionHandler of your API request, use `Date().timeIntervalSince(date: startDate)` to calculate the number of seconds that passed.

Assuming you have a function for your requests that is returning a closure as a completion handler, this is how you can measure its execution time:

```
let startDate = Date()
callMyAPI(completion: { returnValue in
    let executionTime = Date().timeIntervalSince(date: startDate)
})
```

Xcode itself doesn't have any profiling tools, but you can use Time Profiler in Instruments, however, I am not sure if would give the correct results for asynchronous functions.

Solution for your specific function: you can save the `startDate` right after the function call. Then you can measure the execution time in several places (included each): right after the network request finishes (at the beginning of the completion handler) and in each `if statement` right before your delegate method is called.

```
func getUserInfoAPI()  {
    let startDate = Date()
    ...
    Alamofire.request(HCConstants.URL, method: .post, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON {  response in
        //calculate the time here if you only care about the time taken for the network request
        let requestExecutionTime = Date().timeIntervalSince(date: startDate)
        do{
            if let error = response.result.error {
                self.hideHud()
                let executionTimeWithError = Date().timeIntervalSince(date: startDate)
                self.delegate?.APIFailureResponse(HCConstants.EXCEPTION_MESSAGES.SERVICE_FAILURE)
                return
            }
            
            //Store Response
            ...
            //Check Success Flag
            if let _ = responseValue["info"] as? String {
                //Call success delegate method
                let executionTimeWithSuccess = Date().timeIntervalSince(date: startDate)
                self.delegate?.apiSuccessResponse(responseValue)
            }
            else {
                //Failure message
                let executionTimeWithFailure = Date().timeIntervalSince(date: startDate)
                self.delegate?.APIFailureResponse(responseValue["message"] as? String ?? HCConstants.EXCEPTION_MESSAGES.SERVICE_FAILURE)
            }
        } catch {print("Exception is there "}
    }
}
```

Comment: I was just about to write something like this.

Comment: What about when api doesn't take any arguement?

Comment: Since there was no code in your question, I couldn't give an exact answer. However, you can always declare `startDate` in your code just before you want to start the measurement and calculate `executionTime` in the completionHandler of the network request itself.

Comment: I thought the OP wanted to use an XCTest to do this? That is not how you measure asynchronous timing in an XCTest.

Comment: @matt I cannot speak for OP, but since the answer was accepted I guess that is not the case. Moreover, from the only sentence mentioning `XCTest` (_"I want to use Xcode (even if XCTest is there)."_) what I understood is that OP doesn't want to use `XCTest` at all.

Comment: I didn't understand what the OP meant either, so we agree on that. :)

Comment: Thanks , i got 5.28927099704742 is the response . Well i am not completely stick with XCTest , this soln also works for me  , Thanks

Answer (score 6):

`response.timeline.totalDuration` is the correct answer.

Answer (score 5):

Alamofire provides the timeline of request just response.timeline.totalDuration it provides time interval in seconds from the time the request started to the time response serialization completed.

Comment: This is no longer available in latest version of Alamofire, Bharat.

Answer (score 3):

In Alamofire 5 `response.metrics?.taskInterval.duration` is the answer.

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?