# Alamofire 5 - file download execution time (Swift 5)

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I've just updated my project from Alamofire 4 to Alamofire 5 and updating code where required, but there's one that I can't find any help in the reference docs or previous posts regarding the time taken to download.

In previous version I used "response.timeline.totalDuration it provides time interval in seconds from the time the request started to the time response serialization completed." from  ([Checking response Time of API in iOS using Swift 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45862023/checking-response-time-of-api-in-ios-using-swift-3/55523640#55523640)).

Any help to get method for Alamofire 5 would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should now use `response.metrics.taskInterval`. This returns a DateInterval describing how long it took from the initiation of the network request to the completion. More info: https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Usage.md#download-progress

If you want to get this duration in seconds try `response.metrics.taskInterval.duration`